# Ads not showing on my website

Tags: javascript, html, css, ads

Here my code for the ad, I can't get the ad to appear on my website. I've tried tons of different ideas, but I cant seem to figure it out. Any advice would be awesome. Thank you guys so much!

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Random Dota Hero</title>
 </head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="randomdotacss.css" media="screen" />
 <body background="pa.jpeg"> 
 <body>
 <script async         src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
 <!-- Leaderboard Ad -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px"
data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxx"
data-ad-slot="xxx"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you have adblock plus? :)

Comment: Sadly I dont, im really confused ha

Comment: Any errors in the browser's console?

Comment: No there is none